# Empty contents of a iframe without touching the src

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I would like to Empty contents of a iframe without touching the src. Probably using jquery. Say some thing like setting the `innerHTML` of body inside iframe to `&nbsp`

I have tried the following and it didnt work

```
$("#Top iframe body").html('&nbsp;');
```

Comment: Can you just $("#Top iframe").remove()? You won't be able to edit the actual body tag inside the iframe.

Comment: i dont want to remove i just want to empty the content so that i reload to older content anytime by just refreshing the i frame

Comment: Why do you need to empty before reloading the older content? I think what cwallenpoole was suggesting was to remove it (because you can't edit it) and then re-add it again with the new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iframe is on a different domain, its contents are off-limits to your page. There's nothing you can do about that - except remove or hide the whole container... or change the `src`.

If it is on the *same* domain, you can do it but the syntax is different - use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

Comment: sample code coz $('#Top iframe').contents().find("body").html('&nbsp;'); didnt work